# Storing the quantity of values from an array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push

I have got two arrays, one containing values with duplicates and the other empty:

```
let cart = [7, 7, 15, 21];
let quantity = [];
```

How can I get the number of times the values occur in the cart array and push it to the quantity array thus getting a result like this:

```
quantity = [2, 1, 1]
```

Where:
7 in the cart array is 2 in the quantity array, 15 and 21 is 1 in the quantity array respectively.

Comment: what if you have another 7 at the end of the array? do you want `[3, 1, 1]` or `[2, 1, 1, 1]`? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: I want [3, 1, 1]. I have tried a for loop and the array method forEach but they are giving me a different result. the forEach method came close, it gave me a result of [1, 2, 1, 1] instead of [2, 1, 1].

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map to keep the number of times item appeared in the cart and then use it to get the array in the form required

```
const cartItemsMap = new Map();

let cart = [7, 7, 15, 21, 7];

cart.forEach(item => cartItemsMap.set(item, (cartItemsMap.get(item) || 0) + 1));

let quantity = [...cartItemsMap.values()];

console.log(quantity); // [3, 1, 1] in the same order as of your cart items
```

**We cannot use object here because the object won't keep the keys in order which I suppose you would want**

Answer (score 1):

An approach with a closure over an object for keeping indices.

```js
const
    cart = [7, 7, 15, 21],
    result = [];

cart.forEach((indices => v => {
    if (v in indices) result[indices[v]]++;
    else indices[v] = result.push(1) - 1;
})({}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the `cart` while using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the number of occurrences of each number. In the end, you would return the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) of this map:

```js
const getOccurences = (cart=[]) =>
  cart.reduce((quantity,num) => {
    const count = 1 + (quantity.get(num) || 0);
    quantity.set(num, count);
    return quantity;
  }, new Map).values();

console.log( ...getOccurences([7, 7, 15, 21, 7]) );
```